# How to create random points outside polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, random

The tool [Create Random Point](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=create_random_points_%28data_management%29) is able to generate a certain number of points within polygons. I am wondering, given a bounding box, is there any way that I can generate random points outside those polygon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I do not like the random point algorithm in ArcGIS. Alternatively, use [Geospatial Modelling Environment's](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/) (GME) `genrandompnts` function. You will be able to identify specific polygons where random points will be excluded (see highlighted area in attached .jpg).  Best of all this software is free.

> GME provides you with a suite of analysis and modelling tools, ranging
>   from small 'building blocks' that you can use to construct a
>   sophisticated work-flow, to completely self-contained analysis
>   programs. It also uses the extraordinarily powerful open source
>   software R as the statistical engine to drive some of the analysis
>   tools. One of the many strengths of R is that it is open source,
>   completely transparent and well documented: important characteristics
>   for any scientific analytical software.

[image]

Comment: Can you give further info on why you don't like the default random points algorithm, and why GME's is more optimal?

Comment: @Aaron Nice one! Haven't tried this since it was Hawth's Modelling Tools - I'll have to download it and give it a crack!

Comment: @Stephen Within the last month, I was generating random points across four classes.  I encountered several issues: 1) ArcGIS produced several points outside of my input polygons 2) Arc had a difficult time dealing with areas too small for my input parameters (e.g.. minimum allowed distance = 50m & points = 50), whereas GME handled these issues by producing random points up until rules were violated then displaying a warning message 3) Arc's RPG is slower than GME's probably due to R's use of local memory.

Comment: Nice one! Does it have a python bounding so that I can do some batch processing @Aaron ?

Comment: @Seen check out automation and batch processing section (p10) in the support document: http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/images/SpatialEcologyGME.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You are going to have to create a donut polygon with the donut hole representing the interior non-point space and some spatial extent representing the bounding area of the polygonal area.

Comment: Just an addendum: with an ArcInfo license you can do this with the [Erase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000m000000) tool

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I just can't resist. Since it is always good to know what is going on under the hood with something like GME, here is a solution in actual R code.

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)

# Create example polygon data
x <- readWKT("POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))")
y <- readWKT("POLYGON ((3 3, 7 3, 7 7, 3 7, 3 3))")

# Calculate difference in polygon geometries to create null polygon
d <- gDifference(x,y)

# Create random sample in non-null polygon
rs <- spsample(d, 20, type="random")  

# Plot results  
plot(d, col="red")
  plot(rs,pch=19,col="black",add=TRUE)
```

This approach is likely very different than how GME does this but is using native R sp spatial classes and a fairly new topology library making the code very efficient. This also gives an example that can easily be wrapped in a for loop.