# Randomly sampling points in R with minimum distance constraint?

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to randomly select a number of points within my data frame (example data below) with a constraint that the minimum distance between the selected point must be greater than a certain distance. I managed to do the randomly selection bit using the `sample` function in R, but I can't figure out how to add the constraint bit into my code. I suppose this must involve using some spatial analysis package in R but I haven't got a clue where to start.

I know ArcGIS has a tool called Create Random Points which can specify the minimum distance between points. But my situation requires a larger number of repeated sampling, thus making me feel doing this in R would be much easier because it can be incorporated with a loop.

Example data:

```
grid_index x        y
grid_168   323012.5 674187.5
grid_169   323012.5 674212.5
grid_292   323037.5 672287.5
grid_293   323037.5 672312.5
grid_368   323037.5 674187.5
grid_369   323037.5 674212.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this either with R or ArcGIS independently.

With ArcGIS, first create a feature class (e.g. shape file) from your grid coordinates. Then use this grid feature class as constraining_extent parameter of "Create Random Points" tool.

The only coding you have to do is to put that tool in a loop which can be achieved via Model Builder or Arcpy.

here is a sample (100 iteration):

```
import arcpy

for i in range(100):
    print i
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management("c:/data/project", "samplepoints", "c:/data/studyarea.shp", "", 500, "", "POINT", "")
```

For R, use [genrandompnts](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/genrandompnts.htm) from spatialecology website. This tool is similiar to ArcGis "Create Random Points" tool.

In addition, there is another thread similiar to your quesiton.

[How to create random points outside polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33838/how-to-create-random-points-outside-polygons)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Are you aware of any equivalent functions in R. Because my previous codes were written in R and I'm not very familiar  with Python, which could make my further customization of the code difficult. In addition what I really need for the output is just a data frame containing the coordinate rather than a shapefile produced by the ArcGIS. Cheers.

Comment: check the updated answer (use genrandompnts function in R)

Comment: I'm reverting back to doing this in ArcGIS, because the `genrandompnts` only allows selecting from  polygon but doesn't allow selecting from a set of points. May I ask in Python, how do I write the results in different files with names differentiated by the loop time? something like `paste("c:/data/", "i")` in R?

Comment: ```"c:/data/Points_"+str(i)```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you correctly, you want to draw a distance-constrained random sample from your data for each observation in the data. This is akin to a K nearest neighbor analysis.

Here is an example workflow that will create a kNN random sample, using a minimum distance constraint, and add the corresponding rowname back to your data.

Add libraries and example data

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
```

Calculate a distance matrix using spDists

```
 dmat <- spDists(meuse)
```

Define minimum sample distance and set to NA in distance matrix. Here is where you would create any type of constraint say, a distance range.

```
min.dist <- 500 
dmat[dmat <= min.dist] <- NA
```

Here we iterate through each row in the distance matrix and select a random sample != NA. The "samples" object is a data.frame where ID is the rownames of the source object and kNN is the rowname of the nearest neighbor. Note; there is some NA handling added just in case no neighbor is found, which could happen with distance constraints.

```
samples <- data.frame(ID=rownames(meuse@data), kNN=NA)
  for(i in 1:nrow(dmat) ) {
    x <- as.vector( dmat[,i] )
      names(x) <- samples$ID
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    if(!length(x) == 0) {
      samples[i,][2] <- names(x)[sample(1:length(x), 1)]
      } else {
      samples[i,][2] <- NA
    }   
  }
```

We can then add the kNN column, containing the rownames of the nearest neighbor, to the original data.

```
meuse@data <- data.frame(meuse@data, kNN=samples$kNN)
  head(meuse@data)
```

We could also subset the unique nearest neighbor observations.

```
meuse.sub <- meuse[which(rownames(meuse@data) %in% unique(samples$kNN)),]
```

There are much more elegant ways to perform this analysis but this workflow gets the general idea across. I would recommend taking a hard look at the spdep library and dnearneigh or knearneigh functions for a more advanced solution.

Comment: Very helpful and very well described.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If one is interested in sampling points with a distance constraint for each polygon, in the meanwhile, there are two nice and fast possibilities: (1) using QGIS ["random points inside polygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed.html) through [RQGIS-package](https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS) , or (2) using [spatstat::rSSI-function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.55-1/topics/rSSI).

In the following examples for (1) RQGIS and (2) spatstat::rSSI:

```
## load relevant packages
if(!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(sf, sp, rgdal, dplyr, mapview, spatstat, maptools, devtools)


## load data and convert to sf
columbus <- readOGR(system.file("shapes/columbus.shp", package="spData")[1]) %>%
              sf::st_as_sf(.)



## start random sampling with distance constraint

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# (1) ... using RQGIS
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

devtools::install_github("jannes-m/RQGIS")
library("RQGIS")

# ... open QGIS tunnel
RQGIS::open_app() # QGIS must be installed 


# ... find suitable algorithm
RQGIS::find_algorithms(search_term = "random")
# [6] "Random points inside polygons (fixed)
# ---------------->qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed"                                          

# [7] "Random points inside polygons (variable)
# ------------->qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsvariable"  


# ... check usage
RQGIS::get_usage(alg = "qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed")
RQGIS::get_args_man(alg = "qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed")


# ... process random points with minimum distance (0.25 degree)
#     using a fixed maximum number (10)
rdnmPts.RQGIS <- RQGIS::run_qgis(alg = "qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed",
                                 show_output_paths = TRUE,
                                 load_output = TRUE, params = list(
                                  VECTOR =  columbus, MIN_DISTANCE = "0.25", 
                                  VALUE = "10",OUTPUT = "rndm_pts.shp"))


# ... take a look on the result
mapview::mapview(list(rdnmPts.RQGIS, columbus))


# ... check number of random points
nrow(rdnmPts.RQGIS)
# [1] 187



# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# (2) ... using spatstat::rSSI ------------------------------------
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

# spatstat::rSSI uses a special format input. Therefore, a function is created
# to transform the simple feature to owin-format.


# init function
genRandomPtsDist <- function(x, seed = 123, dist = 10, n = Inf, 
                             maxit = 100, quiet = TRUE, ...)
{

  # get start time of process
  process.time.start <- proc.time()

  # get crs
  crs <- sf::st_crs(x = x)

  # convert simple feature to spatial polygons
  x.sp <- x %>% as(., "Spatial") %>%  as(., "SpatialPolygons")


  # convert to owin object
  x.owin <- x.sp %>%
    slot(., "polygons") %>%
    lapply(X = ., FUN = function(x){sp::SpatialPolygons(list(x))}) %>%
    lapply(X = ., FUN = spatstat::as.owin)


  # generate random sampling with distant constraint (can be parallelized)
  pts.ppp <- lapply(X = 1:length(x.owin), FUN = function(i, x.owin, r, n, quiet, 
                                                         seed, maxit, ...)
  {
    if(quiet == FALSE) cat("Run ", i, " of ", length(x.owin), "\n")
    set.seed(seed)
    spatstat::rSSI(r = r, n = n, giveup = maxit, win = x.owin[[i]], ...)
  }, quiet = quiet, x.owin = x.owin, r = dist, n = n, seed = seed, maxit = maxit, ...)


  # back-conversion to simple feature
  pts.sf <- pts.ppp %>%
    lapply(X = ., FUN = function(x) sf::st_as_sfc(as(x, "SpatialPoints"))) %>%
    do.call(c, .) %>%
    sf::st_sf(., crs = crs)


  # get intersected items
  pts.inter.x <- sf::st_intersects(x = pts.sf, y = x) %>% unlist

  if(length(pts.inter.x) != nrow(pts.sf))
  {
    warning("Some sample points are outside a polygon")
  } else{
    pts.sf$In <- pts.inter.x
  }


  # get time of process
  process.time.run <- proc.time() - process.time.start
  if(quiet == FALSE) cat(paste0("------ Run of genRandomPtsDist: " , 
    round(x = process.time.run["elapsed"][[1]]/60, digits = 3), " Minutes ------\n"))

  return(pts.sf)
} # end of function



## Using the defined function, now one can generate a random sample.
# ... process random points with minimum distance (0.25 degree) 
#     using a fixed maximum number (10)
rdnmPts.rSSI <- genRandomPtsDist(x = columbus, dist = 0.25, n = 10, quiet = FALSE)


# ... take a look on the result
mapview::mapview(list(rdnmPts.rSSI, columbus))


# ... check number of random points
nrow(rdnmPts.rSSI)
# [1] 171
```