# Random selection of points in SpatialPointsDataFrame R object with distance constraint

Tags: r, select-by-location, random

I need to select points randomly (without replacement) from a SpatialPointsDataFrame (input object) in R with a minimum distance of 3,000 meters between them. I want to get random 50% of all points. I know that "Create Random Points" tool from ArcGIS, as mentioned before [Randomly sampling points in R with minimum distance constraint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/163287/130305), can do this processing, but I really need
to do this inside R. I tried to use sample() function but I still did not realised how to set the geographical constraint. I tried to run QGIS inside R, but it seems that QGIS does not have a tool for that.

```
> input
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 205 
extent      : 203294.5, 259880.6, 7600123, 7668676  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 3
names       :     Sites, Long_X,   Lat_Y 
min values  : CPF - 050, 203295, 7600120 
max values  : JES - S94, 259881, 7668680 


> head(input)
Sites Long_X   Lat_Y
1 CPF - 050 235441 7617150
2 CPF - 052 234106 7615740
3 CPF - 054 232683 7614280
4 CPF - 056 233863 7614420
5 CPF - 058 234012 7612890
6 CPF - 062 236929 7612850

rdm_input <- sample(x= nrow(input), size=(0.5*205), replace= FALSE)
[1] 167 189 79 80 126 129 144 100 4 109 170 72 123 73 132 93 169 5 134 176 196 
158 152 183 23 136 180
[28] 130 12 142 179 11 13 66 22 2 96 29 54 137 120 171 184 36 113 3 81 115  30 
85 61 162 98 102
[55] 103 181 90 133 56 174 76 201 150 197 14 86 118 121 28 97 160 178 1 186 
141 163 172 32 65 168 74
[82] 114 182 128 131 67 70 165 187 185 69 17 194 16 154 119 192 156 106  25 
101 198 105 108 151 125 190 10
[109] 84 38 51 161 40 94 45 19 145 75 42 122 117 49 87
```

Comment: You could repeatedly select points at random from your input, and create a 3km buffer zone for each selected point, and remove any input points in that buffer zone from the input points. But you can't guarantee this will not remove all points such that you cant select 50% of the input points. Also, it may or may not complete depending on which points are selected at random.

Comment: Why not use the solution in the post you linked to? The last answer is entirely in R.

Comment: Because the only solution that works for me is the ArcGIS one. @JeffreyEvans , your suggestion for using distance matrix return repeted points and do not set a fixed number of points. How can I solve it?

Comment: @JeffreyEvans the last answer (by raff-k) in the linked question uses spatstat::rSSI which is *generating* sets of points rather than *sampling from* existing points, unless I've misunderstood the somewhat curly twisty code...

Comment: You have N points, and there are N-choose-N/2 subsets of half the points, M of which satisfy your distance constraint, with `0 < M < (N-choose-N/2)`. Do you  want to select one of these constraint-satisfying selections with uniform probability over the set of all constraint-satisfying solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added a function "sample.distance" to the development version of [spatialEco package](https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco). You can install the development version from GitHub using: `devtools::install_github("jeffreyevans/spatialEco")`

I included a *replacement* argument to allow for sampling with or without replacement. I also added a *d.max* argument that allows for maximum as well as minimum (*d*) sampling distance. The defaults are no replacement (FALSE) and no maximum sampling distance. The trace argument is to print min/max sample distances for each random samples as well as the number of iterations for distance convergence.

Please note that just because you specify a condition for your data does not mean that it can actually be met. Here is an example using the meuse data. The data cannot meet the condition of a 500m minimum sampling distance for greater than ~15 points (n for 50% sample is 78). This is obviously dictated by the configuration of the randomization but n should not vary that much. I added error checking for non-convergence and the function will return the subsample on however many samples can be identified using the given conditions.

```
library(sp)
library(spatialEco)
data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x+y

p = round( nrow(meuse) * 0.50, 0 )
sub.meuse <- sample.distance(meuse, n = p, d = 500, trace = TRUE)  
  plot(meuse,pch=19, main="min dist = 500")
    points(sub.meuse, pch=19, col="red")
```

If you end up using this function in your research, please cite the package.

Comment: Evans, I tried to install the package as you suggested `devtools::install_github("jeffreyevans/spatialEco")` but I got this error message:
"Error in read.dcf(path) : 
  Found continuation line starting '             role =  ...' at begin of record."

Comment: I solved the installation issue but when a I run `sample.distance` function I got this error message: "Error in sp::spDistsN1(s, x[rs, ], longlat = latlong) :  pts must have two columns"

Comment: This is an odd error, can you make your data available?

Comment: I sent the data to your github email address. I did that because I do not know how to make my data available here.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `@proj4string`. When this is `NA`, the sample.distance run without error, but when I have a projection system defined (like `+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs`) I got the error message

Comment: I tracked this error down to a change in the sp::spDistsN1 function. It was behaving very strangely, even when just using coordinate matrices which negates any issues with proj4string. Rather than fight with the function, I changed how the distance matrix is being derived and the sample.distance function is now working as expected.

Comment: It's working perfectly, Mr. Evans! Thank you so much for your help!!!